# Show only unique items returned from array based on checked

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have an issue which the solution is escaping me right now..

I have an array with contact types, when I pass a typ (say TA) I want to list the checkboxes with the checkboxes checked but also list all others with the checkbox not checked.. I don't want duplicates though.. so if "6230" is checked, don't show the other ones with "6230"..  This way, they can add type "TA" to other locations..  Hope I am explaining this ok.. I did put together a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-kate-02cnj1?file=/src/App.tsx) with an example

Ideally, list the checked ones at the top of the list..

Comment: You should add code here only. There is nothing on codesandbox link also.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save.. should work now

Comment: Instead of `return data?.map`, please try: `return data?.sort(({contact_type}) => (contact_type[0] === typ ? -1 : 1)).map((item: any, i: number) => {....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list the checked ones at top. Then you have to apply a sort function before you map through your data and render it. Your updated function would look something like below. Everything is same. Just a filter function is added before map

```
const getEditCampusCodes = (typ: string) => {
    return data?.sort(item => { // Sort your checked field data at top
      if(item.contact_type[0] === typ) {
        return -1
      }else{
        return 1
      }
    }).map((item: any, i: number) => {
      const campus = item["campus_code"] + " - ";

      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <label>
            {campus +
              item["campus_code_name"] +
              ", " +
              item.address_line1 +
              ", " +
              item.city +
              ", " +
              item.state_code +
              " " +
              item.zip}
            <input
              id={campus}
              value={campus}
              type="checkbox"
              checked={item.contact_type[0] === typ}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
```

Comment: The sort worked.. though I had already added it.. honest! :)  Anyone have suggestions on removing the duplicates?

Comment: You can insert a filter condition before map. Where you can have an array where you store id's of encountered item. If item exists in list you return false else you return true.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issues, did not have unique ID's